# SVG timeline chart

Tags: html, svg, charts

I'm trying to build a chart similar to this excel one http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/timeline-chart-in-excel.php
What I'm looking for is an embeded SVG timeline, with the data I provide.
I have no problem with this excel tutorial, but now I'm trying to make the same in HTML or SVG, and I'm quite lost.
Could anyone tell me any advice, or something where I could start?

Thanks to all!

Comment: I'd start off with a search for 'SVG charts' - there is probably something out there. Failing that, it is quite possible to do your own. Do some beginner SVG exercises (search for these) to see how lines and text are rendered. As it stands, this question is a bit too broad, but if you can break the problem down into pieces and ask specific questions where you are getting stuck, people will be able to offer more directed advice.

Comment: Do you need a one-off chart or something to generate such a chart dynamically with changing data?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) instead of making your own. Have a look at [the demo page](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked) and I guess you'll find what you need.

Highcharts use SVG for graphics rendering on standard browsers, and VML for legacy IE browsers.

[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/) is another option, but I'm not too familiar with that.